# MySql Query For Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to edit a Wordpress plugin. My code is below. The parts in which I'm stuck is documented in the code. Could you show me the correct way to write the code please?

Thanks.

```
<?php
global $wpdb; //I think this is correct
//I need help to convert the 2 lines below to a Wordpress friendly query
$query1="SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE user_login LIKE '%z%'"; 
$result1 = mysql_query($query1);
//I want to put the search results into the example below
if ( $user_login == 'admin' || $user_login == 'joe' ) {
$do_something;
}
?>
```

**Latest Update**
Thank you all for your advice. I think I've got the 1st part right thanks to all your advice. It goes like this:

```html
<?php
global $wpdb;
$my_table = $wpdb->prefix."users";
$my_query = "Select user_login from $my_table where user_login LIKE '%z%' ";
$my_results = $wpdb->get_results($my_query);
?>
```

In second part, how do I put the search results into the foreach loop? Lets assume that I have 100 records in the search results. How do I loop through all the 100 records using the code below:

```html
<?php
foreach($my_results as $user_data)
{
  if($user_data -> user_login === 'admin' || $user_data -> user_login === 'joe' //all hundred records need to go inside here. How do I do that?)
  // do something
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

No, and no.

Problem #1: don't *ever* use `mysql_query()` in new mySQL client code.  Use [mysqli or PDO](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059) instead.  The old API has been deprecated for a long time now.

Problem #2: Never *ever* pass text parameters directly from user into into a SQL query.  This leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  *Always* use [prepared statements](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java) where applicable.

Problem #3: you don't need to be using a mySQL API with Wordpress [$wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) anyway.

You can find several tutorials, including this:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/21/interacting-with-the-wordpress-database/

In your case:

```
<?php
  global $wpdb;

  $query1 = "SELECT user_login FROM wp_users WHERE user_login LIKE '%z%'"; 
  $myrows = $wpdb->get_results($query1);

  foreach ($myrows as $user) {
    if ($user->user_login == 'admin' || $user->user_login == 'joe' ) {
       ...
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use 'wp_' prefix directly in your query. Instead of it, make use of $wpdb->prefix. You can store your table name in one variable and then use it.

Instead of making use of == , make use of === in your if condition.

You are using * (all columns) in your query so, inside foreach loop you can access all your table columns using -> as follows:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

$my_table = $wpdb->prefix."users";
$my_query = "Select * from $my_table where user_login LIKE '%z%' ";
$my_results = $wpdb->get_results($my_query);

foreach($my_results as $user_data)
{
  if($user_data -> user_login === 'admin' || $user_data -> user_login === 'joe')
  // do something
}
?>
```